# View Controller not respecting XIB autoresizing mask

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

A UIView subclass was created in a XIB of type `CustomUIView: UIView`.  It contains several outlets, each one constraint using autoresize (NOT auto layout).

[image]
[image]
[image]

This XIB's view is loaded like this:

```
// In CustomUIView class

  // Initializer used by Interface Builder.
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    initialize()
  }

  func initialize() {
    // Load the view
    let contentView = // typical func to load view from NIB. Owner argument is self. 
    addSubview(contentView)
   }
```

This CustomUIView is added to a view controller like this: 
[image]

The issue is that the view controller's view is not respecting the autoresizing parameters defined in the XIB.

[image]

Now, in theory one can tell the view controller's view to `clip to bounds` but that is not a proper solution. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to set the frame of your `contentView` when it is loaded from the xib.

Comment: `contentView.frame = bounds` does not produce any change.

Comment: I'm seeing 2 issues right away. A view instantiated in a storyboard doesn't automatically get instantiated from a xib. Have you verified that the xib is even being used? Also, you're mixing auto layout (in the storyboard) with autoresizing masks, which doesn't always work right. Does it work if you switch to auto layout in the xib?

Comment: the view is instantiated in its xib. See `initialize()`. When the storyboard instantiates the XIB via the storyboard (because we have told it that the `UIView` is actually a `CustomUIView: UIView`, it will initialize the xib using `init(coder:)`, which then calls ìnitialize()`. I did try using auto layout for everything but did not work, which tells me something's wrong about the frame or passing the constraints from one view to another.

Comment: found the issue. Thx a lot @DonMag. If you change yours to include what I put, I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @anr - I made another edit to my answer... including another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tough to tell, without seeing more details, but...

Here is an example that's working for me (pretty close to the layout you show):

[image]
[image]
[image]

How it's laid-out in Storyboard:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Rotated (to show the auto-resizing):

[image]

---

**TwoLabelView.swift** class:

```
class TwoLabelView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var topLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var botLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TwoLabelView", bundle: nil)
        nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)

        contentView.frame = self.bounds

    }
}
```

and, source to **TwoLabelView.xib** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15505" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15510"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="TwoLabelView" customModule="scratchy" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="botLabel" destination="AKB-d8-jMk" id="QpL-mN-x4M"/>
                <outlet property="contentView" destination="iN0-l3-epB" id="klb-G5-hj6"/>
                <outlet property="topLabel" destination="btE-jS-Ur5" id="LkK-0w-J4z"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="233" height="71"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="btE-jS-Ur5">
                    <rect key="frame" x="16" y="8" width="197" height="21"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.79527050256729126" green="0.96349185705184937" blue="0.73112398386001587" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="AKB-d8-jMk">
                    <rect key="frame" x="16" y="37" width="197" height="21"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.47790580987930298" blue="0.99864691495895386" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.68716365098953247" green="0.31972628831863403" blue="0.86903256177902222" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vUN-kp-3ea"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="282.39999999999998" y="-218.1409295352324"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

---

**Edit**

Another view of the xib in IB:

[image]

Notes:

- File's Owner is set to our custom class
- The xib's view itself is connected to `@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!`

---

**Edit 2**

To make sure the view loaded from the xib resizes correctly, either:

A) Set the `Layout` property for `contentView` in the xib to `Translates Mask Into Constraints`, or

B) If `Layout` is set to `Automatic`, we can modify our `setup()` func:

```
func setup() {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TwoLabelView", bundle: nil)
    nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)

    // make sure we're using the right sizing method
    if contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints == false {
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }

    contentView.frame = self.bounds

}
```

Comment: great. It means there's got to be some flag that I have set/unset.Q: where do you define `contentView` in your xib init.

Answer (score 1):

Thx @donmag for indirectly pointing out the solution.

Here is what the author did not have that @donmag had.

The autoresize masks need to be translated into contraints:

1. Click your XIB's view.
   [image]
2. Change the layout property to "translates masks into constraints". 
   [image]